# UINavigation bar color not shown after perform segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar

I'm working on an app using **Karbon Kit** for **paging** and **SWRevealViewController** for **sideMenu** everything is working fine but I'm stuck from two hours on a strange issue.

In my `AppDelegate`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x339933)];
UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
```

It works for all but when I come from other `ViewController` to `home ViewController` the bar tint is automatically changed to white.
Any help or any idea where I did wrong. 
Thanks.
`Avoid english grammar mistakes , week in english`

Comment: Try removing this line. `UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor;`

Comment: you have to set the navigation bar tint color to your ravel view's navigation too.

Comment: that problem is only in this viewcontroller , all are functioning well

Comment: @RoyNakum ....I tried.. its do nothing

Comment: In your "Easy Pay Tax" controller, please try to set barTintColor that you required.

Comment: @RoyNakum, same result again

Comment: Try putting the code into the viewwillappear of the homeViewController

Comment: @SubhashSharma  I am facing same problem like you how  you solved it .

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x339933)];
UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
```

inside the viewDidLoad of the ViewController of the top view.

Every time the view is selected from the menu it is recreated and the navigation bar is reset to the default white. Having that code in the appDelegate only sets it the very first time you load your app. But putting it in the viewDidLoad of the ViewController that is being selected makes sure the color is set every time the view is recreated.

Comment: Then there must be something else in your code that's changing it.